# How to enable O_NONBLOCK flag for a named pipe using vb.net?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I've written a vb.net code for Named Pipe server and named pipe client. As named pipe works in half duplex mode, the **READ** operation initiated by the server blocks the pipe until client WRITES some data to the pipe. So Server is unable to proceed with **WRITE** operation though Client has not written anything in the pipe

1.Will enabling O_NONBLOCK flag resolve this issue?
2.If enabling of O_NONBLOCK falg will resolve the issue, how it can be done in VB.net or C#?

Answer (score 0):

Based on MSDN documentation, Named pipes support full duplex communication.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-named-pipes-for-network-interprocess-communication

Try by setting `PipeDirection.InOut` in the constructor,  for `NamedPipeServerStream` and `NamedPipeClientStream`